# Python Poloniex API Call

Tags: python-3.x, api, urllib, poloniex

I have the following code that I am trying to make an API call to Poloniex according to [their instructions](https://poloniex.com/support/api/)

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import json
import time
import hashlib
import codecs
import hmac 
import time


Key = "whatever your key is"
Sign = "whatever your secret is"

def returnBalances(balances):
    nonce = int(round(time.time()-599900000)*10)
    parms = {"returnBalances":balances,
             "nonce":nonce}

    parms = urllib.parse.urlencode(parms)
    hashed = hmac.new(b'Sign',digestmod=hashlib.sha512)
    signature = hashed.hexdigest()

    headers = {"Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
               "Key":Key,
               "Sign":signature}

    conn = urllib.request.urlopen("https://poloniex.com")
    conn.request("POST","/tradingApi",parms,headers)

    response = conn.getresponse()
    print(response.status,response.reason)

returnBalances('balances')
```

When I run this I get this error message

```
HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can catch HTTP errors with `urllib.error.HTTPError`
- POST data should be bytes, so you have to encode `parms`
- `urllib.request.urlopen` returns a `HTTPResponse` object, which has no `request` method.
  If you want to set headers and other parameters you should use `urllib.request.Request`
- According to the [api docs](https://poloniex.com/support/api/) the post parameters should be 'nonce' and 'command', so i modified your function to accept 'returnBalances' as a parameter and use it in `parms["command"]`

---

```
def api_call(command):
    nonce = int(round(time.time()-599900000)*10)
    parms = {"command":command, "nonce":nonce}
    parms = urllib.parse.urlencode(parms).encode()

    hashed = hmac.new(Sign.encode(), parms, digestmod=hashlib.sha512)
    signature = hashed.hexdigest()
    headers = {"Key":Key, "Sign":signature}

    req = urllib.request.Request("https://poloniex.com/tradingApi", headers=headers)
    try:
        conn = urllib.request.urlopen(req, data=parms)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        conn = e
    print(conn.status,conn.reason)
    return json.loads(conn.read().decode())

balances = api_call("returnBalances")
```

Comment: That's really nice looking code man thanks so much for clearing that up, very helpful. When I run the script however I still seem to be getting "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'" I am assuming this has to be converted to a byte stream and if so how might one do that?

Comment: That's strange, [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) accepts string or bytes (assuming that the exception was raised by `json.loads(conn.read())`). Still, you can decode the response to string, see updated code

Comment: OK, that fixed it thank you! No errors this time but 403 Forbidden :-(

Comment: What do you get with `print(balances)`?

Comment: Oh right..I get "{'error': 'Invalid API key/secret pair.'}" I am assuming I need to generate a new one?

Comment: No, wait. In `hmac.new` you pass `'Sign'` (string not value) as key. Also you don't update with `parms`. Updated my answer, try again.

Comment: Perfect mate! Your a champ!!

Comment: Very glad i could help!